# Multi-homed TCP server and client stuck in a loop

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, fork

This is my first try to realize a multi-homed file server (kind of) using fork(). The intention is to handle multiple hosts that send operations in the form 'create delete open close write read seek -filetarget ...' (e.g. create -hello.c write -hello.c delete -hello.c).

**SERVER**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<ctype.h> 
#include<netdb.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define BACKLOG 10

extern int inet_ntoa();
extern int inet_pton();

int master(int, int);
int control(char []);
int execute(int, int, char [], char [], char[], int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int server, accepted, porta, nuovo;
struct sockaddr_in listener, client;
socklen_t len;    

if(argc!=2){    //CONTROLLO PARAMETRI
    printf("Errore nei parametri.\n");
    return -1;
}else porta = atoi(argv[1]);    //CONVERSIONE NUMERO DI PORTA

if((server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP))<0){    //CREAZIONE DELLA SOCKET
    perror("Errore nella creazione della socket.");
    return -1;
}

memset(&listener, 0, sizeof(listener)); //SETTAGGIO ATTRIBUTI LISTENER
client.sin_family = AF_INET;
client.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
listener.sin_port = htons(porta);

if(bind(server, (struct sockaddr *)&listener, sizeof(listener)) < 0){   //BINDING SERVER
    perror("Errore binding!");
    return -1;
}

if(listen(server, BACKLOG) < 0){    //LISTENING
    perror("Errore listening!\n");
    return -1;
}

printf("Socket inizializzata con successo..\n");
sleep(2);
system("clear");

while(1){

    printf("FATHER: *** in attesa ***\n");
    len = sizeof(client);
    accepted = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len); //ACCETTO NUOVA CONNESIONE SU ACCEPTED
    if(accepted < 0){
        perror("Errore nella accept!");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("FATHER: *** connessione stabilita con il client %d ***\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));

    nuovo = fork(); //FORK()
    if(nuovo == 0){     //FIGLIO
        master(accepted, server);      
    }else if(nuovo < 0){
        perror("Errore fork!");
        exit(-1);
    }else close(accepted);
}

return 0;

}
int master(int accepted, int server){

        int  fd, i, k, j, flag;
        char richiesta[256], operazione[256], result[256], file[256], file_opened[256];

        printf("Figlio\n");
        close(server);  //CHIUDO SERVER CHE HO EREDITATO E NON MI SERVE
        recv(accepted, richiesta, sizeof(richiesta), 0);  //RICEVO RICHIESTA
        //printf("Richiesta -> %s", richiesta);
        if(strcmp(richiesta,"exit") == 0){  //SE RICHIESTA DI USCITA, ESCO
            close(accepted);
            exit(0);
        }

        fd = -1;    //AZZERO GLI INDICI E PONGO IN STATO DI ERRORE fd
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        i = 0;
        while(i < strlen(richiesta)){       //FINCHÈ LA RICHIESTA NON È STATA ESAMINATA PER INTERO
            while(richiesta[i] != '-'){         //FINCHÈ NON INCONTRO UN CARATTERE "-"   
                operazione[j] = richiesta[i];   //COPIO OGNI LETTERA DI RICHIESTA IN OPERAZIONE
                j++;                            
                i++;
            }
            operazione[strlen(operazione) - 1] = '\0';  //TERMINO LA STRINGA CON '\0'
            i = i+1;                                    //AVANZO DI UNO SUPPONENDO DI TROVARMI SU UNO SPAZIO
            while(richiesta[i] != ' '){                 //FINCHÈ NON TROVO UN ALTRO SPAZIO
                file[k] = richiesta[i];                 //COPIO OGNI LETTERE DI RICHIESTA IN FILE
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            if(!isalpha(file[strlen(file) - 1]))file[strlen(file) - 1] = '\0';  //TERMINO LA STRINGA CON '\0'
            flag = control(operazione);                                         //CONTROL VERIFICA LA VALIDITÀ        
            if(flag == -1) strcpy(result,"Errore nella richiesta!\n\0");        //SE ERRORE, RESULT CONTERRÀ IL MESSAGGIO DI ERRORE
            else execute(flag, fd, result, file, file_opened, accepted);   //ALTRIMENTI SI PROCEDE CON L'ESECUZIONE DI QUANTO CHIESTO
            send(accepted, result, sizeof(result), 0);     //SENDO IL RISULTATO    
            memset(result, '\0', sizeof(result));                   //AZZERO LE STRINGHE ED I CONTATORI UTILIZZATE
            memset(file, '\0', sizeof(file));
            memset(operazione, '\0', sizeof(operazione));
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
        }
        send(accepted, "end", sizeof("end"), 0);    //NOTIFICO LA FINE DELL'ESECUZIONE E CHIUDO
        close(accepted);
        printf("Fine figlio\n");
        exit(0);
 }

 int control(char operazione[]){

    if((strcmp(operazione,"write"))==0) return 1;
    else if((strcmp(operazione,"read"))==0) return 2;
    else if((strcmp(operazione,"seek"))==0) return 3;
    else if((strcmp(operazione,"open"))==0) return 4;
    else if((strcmp(operazione,"close"))==0) return 5;
    else if((strcmp(operazione,"delete"))==0) return 6;
    else if((strcmp(operazione,"create"))==0) return 7;
    else return -1;

 }

 int execute(int flag, int fd, char result[], char file[], char file_opened[], int client_descriptor){

char testo[8192], off[5];
int offset;
char operation[3][6] = {"read\0", "write\0", "seek\0"};
char noop[] = "noop";

if(fd != -1){
    if(strcmp(file_opened, file) != 0){
        strcpy(result,"Errore, il file aperto non è quello sul quale si vuole operare!\n\0");
        return -1;
    }
}

switch(flag){
    case 1: //write
        if(fd == -1){
            strcpy(result,"Errore, nessun file aperto!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }else{
            send(client_descriptor, operation[1], strlen(operation[1]), 0); //ask for text over network
            recv(client_descriptor, testo, sizeof(testo), 0);
            while(lockf(fd, F_TEST, 0) != 0);
            lockf(fd, F_LOCK, 0);
            write(fd, testo,sizeof(testo));
            lockf(fd, F_ULOCK, 0);
            memset(testo, '\0', sizeof(testo));
        }
        break;
    case 2: //read
        if(fd == -1){
            strcpy(result,"Errore, nessun file aperto!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }else{
            send(client_descriptor, operation[0], strlen(operation[0]), 0);
            while(read(fd, testo, sizeof(testo)) > 0) send(client_descriptor, testo, strlen(testo), 0);  
        }
        break;
    case 3: //seek 
        if(fd == -1){
            strcpy(result,"Errore, nessun file aperto!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }else{
            send(client_descriptor, operation[2], strlen(operation[2]), 0);
            recv(client_descriptor, off, sizeof(off), 0);
            offset = atoi(off);
            while(lockf(fd, F_TEST, 0) != 0);
            lockf(fd, F_LOCK, 0);
            lseek(fd, (long int)offset, SEEK_SET);
            lockf(fd, F_ULOCK, 0);
        }
        break;
    case 4: //open
        send(client_descriptor, noop, sizeof(noop), 0);
        if(fd == -1){
            if((fd = open(file, O_RDWR))<0){
                strcpy(result,"Errore, file inesistente!\n\0");
                return -1;
            }else strcpy(file_opened, file);
        }else{
            strcpy(result,"Errore, un file è già aperto!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    case 5: //close
        send(client_descriptor, noop, sizeof(noop), 0);
        if(fd == -1){
            strcpy(result,"Errore, nessun file aperto!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }else{
            close(fd);
            memset(file_opened, '\0', strlen(file_opened));
        }
        break;
    case 6: //delete
        send(client_descriptor, noop, sizeof(noop), 0);
        if(strcmp(file_opened, file) == 0){
            strcpy(result,"Errore, il file da eliminare è attualmente aperto!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }else if(remove(file) < 0){
            strcpy(result,"Errore, il file da eliminare non esiste!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    case 7: //create
        send(client_descriptor, noop, sizeof(noop), 0);
        if(open(file, O_CREAT)<0){
            strcpy(result,"File inestente, creane uno prima di scriverci!\n\0");
            return -1;
        }
        break;
}
strcpy(result,"\nSuccesso!\n\0");
return 0;

}
```

Server create a listening socket, accept a new connection, fork() itself, father goes back to listen and child serves the client.
In specific, child receive the client request and break it into two pieces: operazione[] that is the operation to perform and file[] which is the target. Then control them and execute the operation. Repeat until request string is terminated.

**CLIENT**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

extern int inet_pton();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int server, porta;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
char result[256], richiesta[256], risposta[256], testo[8192];
socklen_t len;

if(argc!=3){                                //CONTROLLO I PARAMETRI
    printf("Errore nei parametri.\n");
    return -1;
}else porta = atoi(argv[2]);                //CONVERTO IN NUMERO LA PORTA

if((server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0){     //CREAZIONE SOCKET
    perror("Errore nella creazione della socket.");
    return -1;
}

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));                         //AZZERO LA STRUTTURA
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                              //SETTAGGIO ATTRIBUTI STRUTTURA
addr.sin_port = htons(porta);
if((inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &addr.sin_addr))<0){
    printf("Settaggio attributi fallito.\n");
    return -1;
}

len = sizeof(addr);   //LUNGHEZZA IN BYTE DELLA STRUTTURA

if((connect(server, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, len))<0){     //CONNESSIONE AL SERVER
    perror("Connessione fallita.");
    return -1;
}

printf("Connessione stabilita!\n");

while(1){   //PER SEMPRE

    sleep(2);
    system("clear");                                                                //PULISCI SCHERMO
    memset(richiesta, '\0', sizeof(richiesta));                                     //AZZERAMENTO RICHIESTA
    memset(risposta, '\0', sizeof(risposta));                                       //AZZERAMENTO RISPOSTA
    do{
        printf("SUPPORTATE (read write seek open close delete create) -file ...\n");
        printf("Richiesta: ");
    }while((fgets(richiesta, sizeof(richiesta), stdin)) == NULL);
    printf("RICHIESTA %s\n", richiesta);
    printf("Hey");                                                        //ACQUISISCO RICHIESTA
    if(strcmp(richiesta,"exit") == 0){                      //SE È UGUALE ALLA STRINGA "exit", ESCE DAL CICLO
        send(server, "exit\0", 5, 0);                       //SENDO "exit" AL SERVER
        close(server);                                      //CHIUDO LA CONNESSIONE
        return 0;
    }
    printf("HELLO");
    send(server, richiesta, strlen(richiesta), 0); //SENDO RICHIESTA

    while(1){
        while(recv(server, risposta, sizeof(risposta), 0) == 0);   //RICEVO LA PRIMA RISPOSTA       
        if(strcmp(risposta,"end") == 0) break;         //RICHIESTA PROCESSATA PER INTERO 

        if((strcmp(risposta,"read") == 0) || (strcmp(risposta,"write") == 0) || (strcmp(risposta,"seek") == 0)){    //SE LA RISPOSTA È UGUALE A "read", "write" O "seek" 
            memset(testo, '\0', sizeof(testo));                                 //AZZERO TESTO
            if(strcmp(risposta,"read") == 0){                                   //SE È UGUALE A "read"                               
                while(recv(server, testo, sizeof(testo), 0) > 0){               //LEGGO TUTTO E STAMPO A VIDEO
                    printf("%s", testo);
                    memset(testo, '\0', sizeof(testo));
                } 
            }else if(strcmp(risposta,"write") == 0){                            //SE È UGUALE A "write"
                printf("Testo da scrivere sul file: ");
                scanf("%s", testo);
                send(server, testo, sizeof(testo), 0);                          //ACQUISISCO IL TESTO E LO MANDO AL SERVER
            }else if(strcmp(risposta,"seek") == 0){                             //SE È UGUALE A "seek"
                printf("Numero di byte spostamento dall'inizio del file: ");
                scanf("%s", testo);                                             //ACQUISISCO NUMERO BYTE E SENDO
                send(server, testo, sizeof(testo), 0);
            }
        }
        recv(server, result, sizeof(result), 0);
        printf("RESULT %s\n", result);                       //STAMPO LA RISPOSTA & AZZERO LA RISPOSTA 
        memset(risposta, '\0', sizeof(risposta));
        memset(result, '\0', sizeof(result));
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Client should send to the server the request, send more text when required (e.g. write or seek) and display it when needed (e.g. read) and then display the state of the operation (Success or Error) sent by the server after execution.

My problem is that after type the request in the client it seems to be stuck and do nothing. No one of the control printf such 'Hey' or 'Hello' are shown.
It appears if I replace `while(recv(server, risposta, sizeof(risposta), 0) == 0);` with `recv(server, risposta, sizeof(risposta), 0);` but then it starts looping as if recv() does not block.

Where are the errors? I'm going mad.

Comment: The [`recv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) function returns zero when the remote system has shut down gracefully. Your client loop `while (recv(server, risposta, sizeof(risposta), 0) == 0);` will exit whenever a message is received (though you won't know how long the message is because you don't capture the length) or if there's an error. But once the server has shut down the connection, your client code goes into a tail spin forever. Rethink what you are doing with that loop! You should be using a condition on `recv()` in place of the `while (1)` loop.

Comment: The printfs are buffered until you output a newline character. So adding a `\n` to the printfs should help with your debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write correct networking code without storing the result of `recv()` into a variable and testing it for (i) -1, indicating an error, (ii) zero, indicating that the peer has closed the connection, or (iii) a positive number, which indicates the number of bytes you have actually received. In case (i) you need to print or log an error, close the socket, and exit; in case (ii) you need to close the socket and exit.

You also cannot assume that entire requests are received in a single `recv()`: you have to loop; or that the buffer resulting from any single `recv()` operation is null-terminated.

You also need to test the result of `send()`: you cannot just assume it succeeded.

Fix all this and try again.

Comment: If I cannot assume that entire request are receive within a single `recv()`, 
how loop should be done?
Is it sufficient `while(send(...)  > 0)`? Or I have to implement something more sophisticated like a function that receive all parts and merge together?

Comment: I have another problem.
The accept() on server side stuck even if a good connection is made by the client. Why?